# how to undo in responsive way large number of files in TFS

Tags: tfs

Today, I managed somehow to checkout all branch, giving me more than 30k files in check-in.
While undoing those pending changes TFS becomes unresponsive. I tried to undo those pending changes project by project but doing so it took me 20 minutes to undo just 1k of files.

What I tried:
I removed the directory with all files. In tfs I converted the mapped folder to "normal folder" but all the files still appears in TFS in pending changes (even though they are removed).

Is there any way to solve my problem? Probably the best solution would be to remove this dir from TFS, and create thid dir once again and get latest, but is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check in the files that you need to check in. (if Any)

Delete your local workspace so that the files are no longer on your hard disk (this is what takes the time to scan)

At the highest point in the source tree that you can safely work from, right click and Undo Pending changes.

this should roll back the pending flag on the TFS server.

once you are happy you can do a get latest against the code that you want back in your workspace.

Answer (score 6):

I undo large amounts of check-outs via the command line.

Start the Developer Console and then cd to your workspace, e.g.

```
cd C:\Code\TFS\
```

Then run the following command:

```
tf undo . /recursive /noprompt
```

It might still take a while, but it should not lock VS and will give you a nice feedback.